# Fetch Outlook contacts from php or using LAMP architecture

Tags: php, outlook, lamp

I have LAMP architecture at my server and i want to import contacts from outlook into my web app. Also I want generic solution that will run on any browser not just IE. 
Is this possible or not? if yes then please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: im not 100% sure if u can get this info directly from PHP because PHP is a server side language and outlook is client side (unless you are hosting your PHP app and outlook on the same machine). You could export your contacts manually from outlook and create an import script for your PHP app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Outlook desktop client will allow you to export your contacts as a `.csv` file. You can write a script to import that file and import it using PHP.

If you use the PHP function [`fgetcsv`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) you can read in the CSV file and parse it as rows of arrays, then push that into what ever storage mechanism you are using on your webapp.

It's also possible to interact with `windows.live.com` to get contacts from the Outlook live service, using this [Outlook.com API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh826535). I've had success interfacing with that using the [PHP Exchange Web Services library](https://github.com/jamesiarmes/php-ews)

Comment: Thanks Dorian. The export mechanism works for outlook. Now I have another requirement where I want to fetch contacts from office 365. I tried there APIs in PHP but no luck.